# Div with repeated background does not render proprely in IE/Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background-image, microsoft-edge

I have this div :

```
<div id="trees"></div>
```

Formatted with this css:

```
#trees {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 37%;
  height: 40%;
  background: url("/img/Tree.png") repeat-x;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

It works fine in all the browsers I tested, with this result:

[image: Normal trees]

Except in IE/Edge, where it looks like this:

Trees with color glitches:
[image]

The weirdest part is that this issue does not affect any other divs with similarly configured background images like the train tracks or the mountains... I have search a lot on this and couldn't seem to find an answer anywhere. I also tried to convert the image from png to gif and I got the same result. How would I fix this for IE/Edge compatibility?

Here is a codepen reproducing the problem in Edge: https://codepen.io/darthmooguy/pen/gmNWwg

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I added an example on codepen!

Comment: I think you need to remove the Adobe XMP meta data from the image using an Adobe image editing product. Renaming the file won't do it. Did you author that image (https://image.ibb.co/k388T5/Tree.png)? or was it from a third-party source?

Comment: Yes, I was the one that authored the image, with Adobe Photoshop!

Comment: Did you try removing the XMP meta-data and saving the file again?

Comment: I did, I tried many way! I used imagemin and re-saved it with XnView, both did not change anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue as you, and whilst this doesn't resolve the cause of the issue, I've found that adding transparent padding to the edges of your image and increasing the background size is a usable workaround in many cases.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRwxbR
Adding the following scaled my background, so set it to an appropriate level.

```
background-size: auto 250%;
background-position: center center;
```

Please ignore the colour change - I was also wondering if a specific colour triggered it based on your initial problem, but it did not.

I might look at this further as my workaround here does not actually solve my issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

here is the tree image (png) saved from Irfanview (save with transparency, no compression)...I'm not sure if Irfanview has stripped the Adobe meta data though.

[image]

as you can see... the colors and transparency color is completely different from the adobe authored source.